# How to edit tables in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

Purpose: To browse for a folder and select it. And to add its properties in columns.

For example, the name of the folder goes in the name column, the location goes in the location, and etc.

For some reason, I am not able to add the properties of selected folder into the table named folderTable. The program seem to know that something is in the first row after I add a folder but it doesn't display the folder itself.

I am learning, so any help is appreciated.

```
public class mainClass2 extends Application {

    Stage window;
    TableView<syncedFolders> folderTable;
    Button file, edit, view, addFolder, printInfo, close, deleteFolder;
    private String name, location, dateModified;
    private long size;

    private double printSize = 0, bytes = 0, kilobytes = 0, megabytes = 0, gigabytes = 0, tempSize = 0;
    private String printSizeAb = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        window = primaryStage;

        HBox topMenu = new HBox();
        file = new Button("File");
        edit = new Button("Edit");
        view = new Button("View");
        topMenu.getChildren().addAll(file, edit, view);

        VBox leftMenu = new VBox();
        printInfo = new Button("Print folder info");
        printInfo.setOnAction(e -> {
            round(printSize, 1);
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Location: " + location);
            System.out.println("Last Modified: " + dateModified);
            System.out.println("Size: " + tempSize + printSizeAb);
        });
        leftMenu.getChildren().add(printInfo);

        HBox botBox = new HBox();
        addFolder = new Button("Add Folder");
        deleteFolder = new Button("Delete Folder");
        close = new Button("Exit");
        addFolder.setOnAction(e -> {
            DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
            chooser.setTitle("JavaFX Projects");
            File defaultDirectory = new File("D:\\");
            chooser.setInitialDirectory(defaultDirectory);
            File selectedDirectory = chooser.showDialog(window);
            name = selectedDirectory.getName();
            location = selectedDirectory.toString();
            size = getFolderSize(selectedDirectory);

            bytes = size;
            kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
            megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
            gigabytes = (megabytes / 1024);

            if (bytes < 1024) {
                printSize = kilobytes;
                printSizeAb = " KB";
            } else if (bytes >= 1024 && bytes < Math.pow(1024, 3)) {
                printSize = megabytes;
                printSizeAb = " MB";
            } else // if (bytes >= Math.pow(1024, 2) && bytes <= Math.pow(1024, 3))
            {
                printSize = gigabytes;
                printSizeAb = " GB";
            }
            addFolder();
            lasModifiedDate();
        });

        // Name column
        TableColumn<syncedFolders, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setMinWidth(200);
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        // location column
        TableColumn<syncedFolders, String> locationCol = new TableColumn<>("Location");
        locationCol.setMinWidth(200);
        locationCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("location"));

        // date modified column
        TableColumn<syncedFolders, String> dateModifiedCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Modified");
        dateModifiedCol.setMinWidth(200);
        dateModifiedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateModified"));

        // size column
        TableColumn<syncedFolders, Double> sizeCol = new TableColumn<>("Size");
        sizeCol.setMinWidth(200);
        sizeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("size"));

        folderTable = new TableView<>();
        folderTable.setItems(getSyncedFolders());
        folderTable.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, locationCol, dateModifiedCol, sizeCol);

        close.setOnAction(e -> closeProgram());
        botBox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        botBox.setSpacing(10);
        botBox.getChildren().addAll(addFolder, deleteFolder, close);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(topMenu);
        borderPane.setLeft(leftMenu);
        borderPane.setCenter(folderTable);
        borderPane.setBottom(botBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 800, 600);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.setTitle("the title");
        window.show();
        window.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            e.consume();
            closeProgram();
        });
    }

    // Get all of the products
    public ObservableList<syncedFolders> getSyncedFolders() {
        ObservableList<syncedFolders> folders = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        folders.add(new syncedFolders("Folder", "D://", "July", 3.4));
        folders.add(new syncedFolders(name, location, dateModified, tempSize));
        return folders;
    }

    public void addFolder() {

        round(printSize, 1);

        folderTable.setItems(getSyncedFolders());
        folderTable.getItems().add(new syncedFolders(name, location, dateModified, tempSize));
    }

    private double round(double value, int precision) {
        int scale = (int) Math.pow(10, precision);
        tempSize = (double) Math.round(value * scale) / scale;
        return tempSize;
    }

    public String lasModifiedDate() {
        Path path = Paths.get(location);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy - hh:mm:ss");
        FileTime fileTime = null;
        try {
            fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("Cannot get the last modified time");
        }
        dateModified = dateFormat.format(fileTime.toMillis());
        return dateModified;
    }

    private long getFolderSize(File folder) {
        long length = 0;
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();

        int count = files.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (files[i].isFile()) {
                length += files[i].length();
            } else {
                length += getFolderSize(files[i]);
            }
        }
        return length;
    }

    private void closeProgram() {
        /**
         * Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION); alert.setTitle("Confirmation
         * Dialog"); alert.setHeaderText("You are about to exit");
         * alert.setContentText("Are you ok with this?");
         * 
         * Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait(); if (result.get() ==
         * ButtonType.OK)
         **/
        window.close();
    }
}


public class syncedFolders {

    private String name, location, dateModified;
    private double size;


    public syncedFolders() {
        this.name = "";
        this.location = "";
        this.dateModified = "";
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public syncedFolders(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }

    public syncedFolders(String name, String location, String dateModified, double size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public String getlocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setlocation(String s) {
        location = s;
    }

    public String getdateModified() {
        return dateModified;
    }

    public void setdateModified(String s) {
        dateModified = s;
    }

    public double getsize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setsize(double d) {
        size = d;
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them - actually it is related ... but then, that's explained in the duplicate question (and any decent tutorial, please see the info tag to find some ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TableView` uses [Properties and Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) to display the data in each column. You have a `CellValueFactory` installed on the columns, but you're populating it usinga `PropertyValueFactory`.

That is the right way to do it, but there's a problem with your `syncedFolders` class. The `PropertyValueFactory` looks into your `syncedFolders` class and tries to find a `Property` with the name you specified.  The problem is that you do not have any properties defined:

```
private String name, location, dateModified;
private double size;
```

These are fields, not properties.

You will need to rewrite your `syncedFolders` class to have observable properties instead, like this:

```
private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
```

Do that for each of your fields, update your constructor and setters/getters and try again!

```
public class syncedFolders {

    private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private SimpleStringProperty location = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private SimpleStringProperty dateModified = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private SimpleDoubleProperty size = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public syncedFolders(
            String name,
            String location,
            String dateModified,
            double size) {

        this.name.set(name);
        this.location.set(location);
        this.dateModified.set(dateModified);
        this.size.setValue(size);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty locationProperty() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location.set(location);
    }

    public String getDateModified() {
        return dateModified.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty dateModifiedProperty() {
        return dateModified;
    }

    public void setDateModified(String dateModified) {
        this.dateModified.set(dateModified);
    }

    public double getSize() {
        return size.get();
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty sizeProperty() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(double size) {
        this.size.set(size);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I would also recommend changing how you populate your table.  Your current `addFolder()` method is adding the item directly to the table's `items` property, but you really should add them to the underlying `ObservableList` that is set as the table's items:

```
public void addFolder() {

    round(printSize, 1);
    folderTable.setItems(getSyncedFolders());
    folderTable.getItems().add(new syncedFolders(name, location, dateModified, tempSize));
}
```

The way `folderTable.setItems()` works is that it binds a list to the `TableView`. But that I mean that any changes made to the list will be reflected in the `TableView` automatically; you should not need to use `folderTable.getItems().add()` at all.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solves the problem. Yes without getting rid of folderTable.getItems().add(new syncedFolders(name, location, dateModified, tempSize)); the properties of the folder were displayed twice. However, the ObservableList seems to be replaced every time I add a new folder.

Comment: That is because your `getSyncedFolders()` method creates a new `ObservableList` every time it is called.

Comment: You should not use `getSyncedFolders()` to add anything to the list. Instead, declare the `folders` list as a class field (at the top of your class file). Then you can just use your `addFolders()` method to add folders to it; you shouldn't need the `getSyncedFolders()` method at all.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code, but hopefully this helps get you closer :)